# create a file name using time in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm pretty new to Powershell and would like to output the result of a command to a file which has a timestamp. Currently I could get the date but I can't get the time. Here is what I have:

```
mstest /testcontainer:"C:\CodedUITests\CodedUISP.dll" /resultsfile:"C:\CodedUITests\TestResults\result $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)$.trx"
```

How can I get the time as well?

Comment: What have you tried  for the time? As you've already worked out, `get-date` accepts .NET formatting strings, and you have the date - adding time is just an extension of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick google search I found [this reference](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-dateformats.html):

```
Get-Date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing almost the same thing! Here's my code:

```
        $outputFile = "$tempLocation\work\$($solutionName)_$((Get-Date -Format s).ToString().Replace('-','').Replace(':','')).trx"

        Write-Verbose "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name): Running MSTest.exe..." 
        Invoke-ExternalCommand MSTest.exe @(
            "/testcontainer:$testContainer",
            "/resultsfile:$outputFile")
```

```

Invoke-ExternalCommand is just an abstracted function that calls the mstest command. Doing this allows me to mock the call making Pester testing easier.

This is what the trc file is named: `SolutionName_20151015T113206.trx`